# Gerar Número Aleatório sem repetição Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Então, quero gerar esse protocolo, com números aleatórios e sem repetição.

Está funcional, ou seja, o código não repete.

Porém, ao clicar gerar protocolo, no clique, ele era pra gerar, ATÉ achar um número aleatório que não repita, porém, se ele não encontra esse número que repete, ele nao adiciona nada na lista.

Estou com uma grande dificuldade pra resolver, alguém com alguma idéia?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="botao"> Gerar Protocolo </button>
    <button type="button" class="botao2"> Postar Protocolos </button>
    <div class="type"> Protocolos: </div>
</body>

<style>
        .type {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
</style>

<script> 

    function geraProtocolo () {
            var max = CheckMaxProtocol();
            var min = 1;

            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + 1;
        }

    function CheckMaxProtocol() {
            var max = 10;
            return max;
    }

    function verificaTotalVetor (vetor) {
        var verificaMaximo = CheckMaxProtocol();
            if (vetor.length >= verificaMaximo-1) {
                console.log("não é possível gerar novos protocolos.");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    var vetor = [];
    var auxiliaProtocolo = document.querySelector(".type");
    var limiteMaximo = CheckMaxProtocol();
    var botao = document.querySelector(".botao");
    botao.addEventListener("click",function() {
        var verificadorVetorCheio = verificaTotalVetor(vetor);

        if (verificadorVetorCheio == true) {
            return;
        }

        var resultado = geraProtocolo();
            vetor.push(resultado);


        for (var i = 0; i<vetor.length; i++) {
            for (var j = i+1; j<vetor.length; j++) {                    
                if (vetor[i] == vetor[j]) { 
                    vetor.pop(vetor[j]);
                    while (tamanhoVetor < vetor.length) {
                        console.log('he');
                        var result = geraProtocolo();
                        if (result != vetor[i]) {
                            vetor.push(result);
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    });

    var botao2 = document.querySelector(".botao2");
    botao2.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if (vetor.length > 0) {
            var novoProtoco = document.createElement("p");
            auxiliaProtocolo.appendChild(novoProtoco);
            novoProtoco.innerHTML = "Protocolo: " + vetor;
        }
    });
</script>
```